# How to change next buttons based on radio button value on same page in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('general', array(
                 'legend'=>Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Template')
                  ));     

$field = $fieldset->addField('slider_type', 'text', array(
                   'label'=> Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Slider Type'),
                   'name' => 'slider_type',
                   'value'=> $config['slider_type'],         
                   ));

$field->setRenderer($this->getLayout()->createBlock('attigo_slider/adminhtml_slider_edit_tabs_config_slidertype'));
```

Now if `$config['slider_type']` value is 'abc' then

**1. fieldset will print** otherwise

**2. fieldset will print.**

```
1. $fieldset->addField('auto_scale', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Auto Scale'),
          'values'    => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toOptionArray(),
          'name'      => 'auto_scale',
          'value'   => $config['auto_scale']
       ));


2. $fieldset->addField('scale_width', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('attigo_slider')->__('Scale Width'),
          'name'      => 'scale_width',
          'value'   => $config['scale_width']
      ));
```